# javascript/jquery grab part of URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, parsing, url

I have for example, https://www.example.com/test1/something?asd=1. Of this example URL I need to grab everything up until and included /test1/. So I would set `var url = https://www.example.com/test1`. The problem is that test1 is dynamic so I can not have any hard coded values.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use a combination of split() and join():

```
var url = "https://www.example.com/test1/something?asd=1";
var result = url.split("/",4).join("/");
```

Here's a JSFiddle of it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/msm3jsvw/